# How to use concatenate function in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.CONCATENATE('A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K'),'0);');
```

Can anyone tell how to use the concatenate function in php Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a formula in the cell, then you need to write it as you would write an Excel formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("A","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
```

if I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1','=CONCATENATE("A","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")');
```

**EDIT**

Trying to interpret what you mean:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.($i+$j),'=CONCATENATE(A'.($i+$j).'," ",D'.($i+$j).')');
```

If $i+$j = 5, then this will write the formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A5," ",D5)
```

in cell E5,

so if cell A5 contains

> Hello

and cell D5 contains

> World

then cell E5 will display the value

> Hello World

Comment: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::CONCATENATE() in C:\wamp\www\XXXXXXXXXXXX\application\controllers\savephpexcel.php on line 111

Comment: @masterprogrammer - what are you trying to do, please explain.... the line of code I answered you with should never give that error. It stores the formula '=CONCATENATE("A","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")' in cell A1 of the current active worksheet

Comment: $insert="INSERT INTO m_productprice(m_product_id,ad_org_id)VALUES(";
$values="1000004, 1000004, 'Y',";
$created=$this->timendate->getCustomDate("%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s",now());
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.($i+$j),$insert);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.($i+$j),"$values");

Comment: now i want to concatenate thse two cells i.e a & d.i have cut down the code as its long and involves more than 50 fields to insert into excel